# what will happen if an optocoupler output is connected to AC?

Tags: opto-isolator

What will happens to the output of an 4n25 if the final user by mistake wires an AC current (12 V . AC)?

Will This destroy the transistor?

I can't find this condition in datasheets.

Answer (score 2):

The [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf) (I recommend linking one in the question, because it can differ slightly between manufacturers!) specifies an emitter-collector breakdown voltage of 7V. This means that if the emitter is over 7V higher than the collector, which would happen during the negative portion of your AC signal, it will not function correctly, probably breaking it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The input reverse voltage rating is 5 V. If you hook up 12 Vac to the input, you will apply a reverse voltage of 12 * sqrt(2) V to the input, almost certainly damaging the device.